# Android TV leanback. How to tell if user is on header navigation from MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

In the Android TV leanback sample the MainFragment has navigation headers and rows.

Is there a way I can tell from the MainActity whether the user is currently on the row headers (navigation on left) or the actual rows of the MainFragment?

```
public class MainActivity extends LeanbackActivity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        MainFragement mf;                 

        if (mf.focusedOnFragmentHeaders) {
            //Do Something
        }
    } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `setBrowseTransitionListener` in BrowseFragment to get header transition state.

---

**UPDATE**

As follow! keep the `withHeaders`

```
setBrowseTransitionListener(new BrowseTransitionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onHeadersTransitionStart(boolean withHeaders) {
       isFocusOnHeader = withHeaders;
   }

   @Override
   public void onHeadersTransitionStop(boolean withHeaders) {
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Is it possible you could give me a code sample? I am having issues implementing this. Thanks!